# Subset from subset of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe df, it contains 10 different variables, including group.name, group.student, and other variables.

I firstly want to select the group with name "papaya", I do `dfByGroup = df[group.name=="papaya",]`, the result is fine.

Then I want to select a specific person called "julia" from the above subset, I do `dfByJulia <- dfByGroup[group.student=="julia",]`, and I view the results with `View(dfByJulia)`, unfortunately, I can still see rows with students' names other than "julia".

Actually the student name "julia" is unique in my data, so I also tried select julia's rows directly from the original data `dfByJulia<- df[student.name=="julia",]`. This time, the subset data is correct.

Why does this happen? Why cannot I do subsetting from a subset with `[` operator? Why must I do it on the original dataframe?

Comment: You forgot a comma: `dfByJulia <- dfByGroup[group.student=="julia",]`

Comment: Also, it looks like you probably did `attach(dfByGroup)`, which puts that df's names on the search path; this allows you to cheat a bit because your code should really be `dfByJulia <- dfByGroup[dfByGroup$group.student=="julia",]`.

Comment: @Thomas  Hi, Thomas, thanks a lot. For your first comment, it was just a typo in stackoverflow, I actually have the "," in my original command . Your second comment is exactly the answer, I forgot I did the "attach" before. Thanks very much.

Comment: That's the single reason why `attach` is dangerous and If you don't want to type $ everytime then prefer `with` and `within`

Comment: @dickoa thanks, I'll use with/within next time :-D